# Listing Keys which have same values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC
(
    key NUMBER(5), 
    val NUMBER(5)
);

insert into ABC (key, val) values (1,1);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (1,2);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (1,3);
insert into ABC (key, val) values (2,3);
```

Desired output:

[image]

I want to find all keys that have the same value 'val'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're OK with a delimited list instead of actual separate columns, you can use aggregation and `listagg()`.

```
SELECT listagg(key, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY key) keys,
       val
       FROM abc
       GROUP BY val
       HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b824dd4ce7d3b9e4ff8f01cdbb7d347d)

Comment: Hi @sticky bit I wanted to list the maximum combination of keys that have the same value. Sorry for editing the question.

Comment: @StackOne: Please don't do that. Roll this question's edit back, so that it doesn't invalidate the answer and post a *new* question for the other problem.

Comment: it's not letting me roll back, seems like there is some error